# newcommand arguments auto prompts

Tags: texmaker

I am using Texmaker and am trying to define a new command that takes some mandatory arguments. But I want it in this way: when user just typed the first few letters of the new command, it will be auto completed with all the `{}`'s that have big dots in it that prompt the user to enter the argument, and the user just need to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to jump to the next `{}` to fill in the argument. i.e. just like the `\frac{}{}` command. 
Below is what I have, but it does not have the nice feature of autocomplete and jumping to the next argument on <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\clause}{mmm}{\ensuremath{(#1 \vee #2 \vee #3 )}}
```

Comment: You're asking for an editor feature; this can't be implemented in TeX alone.

Comment: Do you mean TexMaker (which I have never used) is supposed to automagically recognize the arbitrary parameters of *every* user-defined command and 'jump' appropriately (simply by parsing the commands defined in the document)? or just this specific one?  If TexMaker can be made to do the former, I might be inclined to give it `emacs+auctex`'s crown for the best *TeX editor.

Comment: FYI, `TeXStudio`, the `texmaker` fork, will automatically recognize *every* user-defined command.

Comment: @hpesoj626 -- what do you mean by 'recognize'?  Do you mean you can *make* it 'recognize' a command?  I'd have thought most editors could do that.

Comment: @jon Sorry. I am wrong about `\NewDocumentCommand` but every user-defined commands and environments through `\newcommand` and `\newenvironment` will automatically have auto-completions like that being sought by OP and there is no more need to do user customizations about these. And of course you are right about most editors having this feature.

Comment: @hpesoj626 -- yeah, OK.  I was thinking the first time around about commands that make use of `xparse` since the OP mentioned it explicitly (though it is not strictly necessary in the example he gave...).  Your answer is worth posting (at first I only saw your comment).

Answer (score 8):

Once you have defined your command as usual in your `.tex` file, click

> **User > Customize Completion**

then type

`\clause{@}{@}{@}`

then click **Add**.

Texmaker will convert the `@` into a dot.

[image]